# Looking for a possible reference for a result on extensions in ergodic theory

Tags: ergodic-theory

There's a result I'd need for something I'm working on. When discussing it with my advisor, she said she's sure she's seen this result somewhere, but isn't sure where. As such, not really sure how to look for it. It looks like it SHOULD be relatively easy to prove from scratch if need be, but seeing as I have other things to work on, if I don't have to freshly prove it, I'd rather not.

Let $(Z,\mu,T)$ be an extension of $(X,\nu,T')$ (both measure preserving dynamical systems). For what I'm doing, I'm assuming $T$ and $T'$ are both invertible, but I don't think that should be necessary here. We know that there exists a measure space $(Y,\eta)$ such that $(Z,\mu,T)$ is isomorphic to $(X \times Y, \nu \times \eta,T)$ (slight abuse of notation, I think, but I've just been assuming without loss of generality that all extensions I'm working with are in this form) with the natural projection onto $X$ being a factor map to $(X,\nu,T')$. In this case, there exists $\varphi: X \times Y \to Y$ such that $T(x,y)=(T'x,\varphi(x,y)).$

Of course, we can view $\varphi$ as a family $\{\varphi_x\}_{x\in X}$ with $ \varphi_x:Y \to Y$ and $\varphi_x(y):=\varphi(x,y)$.

What I want: $(Y,\eta,\varphi_x)$ is a measure-preserving dynamical system for (almost) all $x \in X$.

Has anyone seen such a result, or better yet able to give a reference for such a result? It seems only natural for this to be true, and like I said, I probably could prove it if need be, but why spend the time if I don't have to?

Edited to add a clarifying comment

Comment: You're question basically reminds me of a skew-product construction, and if I recall correctly there's a factorization/disintegration theorem due to Rohlin that describes extensions as skew-products. I would try to look for that theorem in Eli's book (it discuss plenty of stuff, not only joinings!), Eli's book also has extensive bibliography.